# Need suggestions in getting the conversation details

Tags: botframework

I am creating a bot using MS Bot framework - NodeJs. The below information needs to be captured for logging (Using the bot.use method i.e. IMiddleware).

Receive:
a. UserId
b. UserInput (text)
c. ConversationId

Send:
1. Name of Intent or dialog name that handled this (that handled the user input text)
2. Bot output text
3. ConversationId
4. UserId

I am unable to get the required detail for the 'send'. Can anyone provide me some suggestions on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main struggle is to log the `name of intent or dialog`. You won't know it in your `send` middleware if you haven't captured it during the `routing` phase. Once the Bot Framework figured out where to send the incoming message, it just invokes that function.

These two articles may help you get what you want. Just recently I played with capturing the conversation's breadcrumbs and also logging a full transcript:

- http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-3-breadcrumbs/
- http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-4-transcript/

If you need to build a reliable capture engine, I would suggest that you didn't use the `session.privateConversationData` like I did and instead built your own storage/log infrastructure to push the events to. Just stream them out with a timestamp and `conversationId` and reconcile on the other end later. The asynchronous nature of everything the bot framework does internally will be haunting you along the way so that's why. Plus, once you scale out beyond testing on a few users and your bot spans multiple processes, you will be out of the single-threaded event loop.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Implemented by triggering an event once the Intent is identified.